# Changing the innerHTML of a certain element when a special picture of a randomised array appears

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to change the innerHTML of button1 when the picture ('/robot.svg') appears. The logic works fine when I comment out the if-clause, however I can't make the if-clause work.

```
<img src="/closed_door.svg" alt="closed_door" id="1">
<button id="button">Good luck</button>



let links = ['/beach.svg', '/robot.svg', '/space.svg']
let pic1 = document.getElementById("1")
let button1 = document.getElementById("button")



button1.onclick = function () {
      pic1.src = links[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]

 if (pic1.src === '/robot.svg') {
  
    button1.innerHTML = 'game over';
  }  
}
```

Thanks for reading or even helping a beginner out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the image name from the `src` when comparing:

```js
let links = ['/beach.svg', '/robot.svg', '/space.svg']
let pic1 = document.getElementById("1")
let button1 = document.getElementById("button")

button1.onclick = function () {
      pic1.src = links[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)];
      let name = (pic1.src).substring((pic1.src).lastIndexOf("/"));
      console.log(name);
      if (name === '/robot.svg') {
           button1.innerHTML = 'game over';
      }  
}
```

```html
<img src="/closed_door.svg" alt="closed_door" id="1">
<button id="button">Good luck</button>
```